# Command button/ link not firing

Tags: button

I am trying to use apex select checkboxes to pass values to the controller values on click on command button. But the button is not firing. On replacing the button with link the link fires only when the link is clicked without selecting any values in the checkboxes(that is does not fire when some values are selected in the select checkboxes). 
Below is the snippet

```
<apex:selectCheckboxes borderVisible="true" value="{!selectedMonth}" styleClass="check">
      <apex:selectOptions value="{!months}" />
</apex:selectCheckboxes>

<div class="grid _margintop10">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <button class="btn primary _fullwidth">
              <apex:commandLink action="{!createnewActivity}" value="Add a new Activity"/>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

The action createnewActivity() is what is not getting fired.

Comment: Can you please send paste controller as well ?

Comment: public void createnewActivity()
    {
        system.debug('!!!!!!!!!!!!');
        system.debug('*******selectcheckboxresult'+selectedMonth);
    }

Comment: Have you tried [example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_selectCheckboxes.htm) ? Can you provide you code with button, selectedMonth property

Comment: @starhunter There is no issue at VF code, you must be missing something at the controller side. Please provide the complete controller code so that I can help you.